# How to apply the Classic theme on my WPF4 form?

Tags: themes, wpf-4.0

We are currently migrating our app from VB6 to Net. As the Net forms will be in the minority we want them to blend in as good as possible with the VB6 forms. I thought that forcibly applying the Classic theme would accomplish this. This should be easy but I can't find how to do it. The examples provided target the Aero theme or Net3 which seems to have differently named referenced assemblies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

1. Reference the classic.xaml file that is embedded in the Framework:

   ```
    <ResourceDictionary>
       <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="/PresentationFramework.Classic;component/themes/classic.xaml" />
       </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
   ```

   `
2. Download the extracted classic.xaml file from [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7812)
   This file holds a reference to the PresentationUI.dll which does not seem to be part of Net 4 framework. There is just one quixotic Control using this reference, so when you remove the reference and the control you are set to go!

More info [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/f737aa07-8381-4617-ad07-b52a5520a527/?prof=required)

Comment: The xaml link is broken.